# How to import data from "excel" to "sybase table" using sql developer?

Tags: excel, sybase, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have connections for both 'oracle' and 'sybase' in my **'Sql Developer'**.

For the *Oracle-Connections* there are options to import data from excel, csv, dsv, etc...
While, for the Sybase-Connections I can't find any import option.

Is there any way to import data from excel file to tables in sybase ?

Comment: What kind of Sybase database are you connecting to?  ASE? SQL Anywhere? Please be more specific when asking questions, it will help.

Answer (score 2):

I have never used SQL developer with Sybase before, I'm not sure it's officially supported. This might also be the reason why the context menu (import from excel) is unavailable.
Possible solutions for your problem:

1. If you use "Sybase SQL Anywhere" check the documentation for "load table" statement, it also supports loading Excel files.
2. Use Interactive SQL client from Sybase to upload you excel file.
3. Use the "INPUT" statement inside Interactive SQL.
4. Export the excel document into a CSV format and load it using the "load table" statement.

I would recommend exporting to a CSV format and then importing into the Database, just be careful with the output from excel to CSV.

Comment: Sql Developer supports to the sybase connections when used with third-party-driver **([jtds](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-may/o38sql-102034.html))**

Comment: While the connection may be supported, not all the features may be the same.  I agree with Bogdan, you may have to extract the data and load it with Sybase tools.

Answer (score 2):

Save Excel in CVS format and then bcp in the file:-

bcp dabase_name..Table_name  in filename -Uuser_name -Ppswd -SServerName -c -t "," -Y

Comment: This is also good way (with native bulk copy tool... If you get problems its possible to verbose error.